# how to add an svg as an icon in react native bottom tab?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native and react
I'm trying to make a custom bottom navigator
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA9tt.png)
I have added the other icons

My current code is

```
// tab array
const TabArr = [
  {
    route: Screen1,label: 'Screen1',type: Ionicons, activeIcon: 'book',inActiveIcon: 'book-outline',
    component: ScreenOne
  },  
 
  {
route: 'Details',label: 'Details',type: Ionicons, 
activeIcon: <logo width="100%" height="70%" />,
inActiveIcon: <logo width="100%" height="70%" />,
    component: DetailsScreen
     },
  {
 route: Screen3,label: 'Screen3',type: Ionicons, activeIcon: 'book',inActiveIcon: 'book-outline',
    component: ScreenThree
}
]
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()
const TabButton = (props) => {
  const { item, onPress, accessibilityState } = props
  const focused = accessibilityState.selected

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={onPress}
      activeOpacity={1}
      style={styles.container}
    >
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Icon
          type={item.type}
          name={focused ? item.activeIcon : item.inActiveIcon}
          color={focused ? 'blue' : 'red'}
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}

export default function MainContainer({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarStyle: {
          }
        }}
      >
        {TabArr.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <Tab.Screen
              key={index}
              name={item.route}
              component={item.component}
              options={{
                tabBarShowLabel: false,
                tabBarButton: (props) => <TabButton {...props} item={item} />
              }}
            />
          )
        })}
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

I need some help with this part

route: 'Details',label: 'Details',type: ,
activeIcon: ,
inActiveIcon: ,
component: DetailsScreen

Thanks in advance